# Which crypto-algorithem uses iOS in NSDataWritingFileProtection and what is the keysize?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security, encryption

I need to know the crypto algorithm and key strength of `NSDataWritingFileProtection`. I would like to know the same things for using the Keychain and `NSFileManager`.

I searched the Apple Developer references:

- [Security Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html)
- [`NSDataWritingOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone)

But found noting specific.

The [Advanced Encryption Standard Algorithm Validation List](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/aes/aesval.html)
 contains multiple entries of Apple using AES 128bit-256bit but nothing in connection to keychain or `NSDataWritingOptions` or `NSFileManager`

Thanks for your help, a better link to the documentation would fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used that source [iPhone in Business - Security Overview](http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/gadgetlab/2009/07/iphone_security_overview.pdf)

AES-256bit in iPhone hardware encryption (page 3 Chapter Encryption)